Запрос к nginx, запрашиваем один файл, подгружаем другой
Буквально недавно стал изучать nginx. До этого сидел на апаче...
В чем рассчитываю разобраться, если в апатче(htaccess). Прописывал правило
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap\.php [NC,L]

И все работало, то как в кофиге(сайта) nginx прописать тоже самое?
location /sitemap.xml {
    rewrite ^/.* /sitemap.php permanent;
}

Просто переадресовывает на файл /sitemap.php в url.
По идеи должно исполнить и отдать содержимое...
Сразу следующий вопрос, ниже прописан следующий блок
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

Не понимаю, как верно прописать первое правило, где именно. Вне данного блока или же в данном блоке возможно прописать. Как то не понятно...
Если возможно там и там. То как лучше?

Убрать permanent и почистить кеш браузера

Работает, хотел бы уточнить rewrite ^/.*.  Для чего данное выражение, в начале строчки, быть может возможно прямой путь от корня указать? Дабы не нагружать сервер при запросе...

Можно сократить до rewrite ^ /sitemap.php; Ничего тут не нужно оптимизировать, эта нагрузка на фоне PHP несущественна
